# A case of a probability graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

I was given the next question:

I am given a graph $G$ with 6 nodes and a probability $p$ of each edge to be created.

I need to prove/disprove that for each $p$, we have a case where either 3 nodes are all connected to each other or none of them are connected to each other.

Any help will be appreciated. 
I tried to solve it by negation but couldn't find a right solution.

Comment: This should not depend on $p$.  I would have thought that $R(3,3)=6$ was enough.  [Wikipedia has a proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Example:_R(3,_3)_=_6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Henry, this is not really a probabilistic question. Are you familiar with Ramsey theory and Ramsey number?

The following result is well known (and easy to prove, see Henry's link) : consider $K_6$ the complete graph on 6 vertices. (all vertices are pairwise connected).

For any any coloring of $K_6$ with two colors (red and blue for instance), you must have a blue triangle or a red triangle.

This relate to your problem by saying that the blue edges are present, while the red ones are not. Hence for any graph on 6 vertices, you must have three vertices forming a triangle, are 3 vertices with no edges.

This is because the diagonal ramsey number $R(3)$ is 6.

Therefore, for any random graph model, (or any way to generate a (simple) graph on 6 vertices), the result holds.